# There is no question that you will not misunderstand this sentence

Tags: writing-style, ambiguity, negation, superlative-degree, inflectional-morphology

The *[MacMillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/there-is-no-question-about-that)* has the following definition for the phrase '*there is no question that*':

> used for saying that something is definitely true

It gives the example:

> There is no question that she has a great voice.

In other words: *It is definitely true that she has a great voice*.

Therefore it appears that the interpretation of:

> There is no question that *boringest* belongs to the grammar of standard English.

must be:

> It is definitely true that *boringest* belongs to the grammar of standard English.

Yet it seems that the author of this sentence actually means that *boringest* does **not** belong to the grammar of standard English. Here is the paragraph in which the sentence is located:

> A corpus is “… a body of texts put together in a principled way, often for the purposes of linguistic research.” (Johansson 1991: 3). Computer technology means that modern corpora are large and easy to manipulate, thus lending themselves well to frequency studies of vocabulary and, to a lesser extent (Granger 2002: 21), grammar.
>   The assumption is that there is a relationship between how frequent a construction is attested and its status in the language. Common forms and structures will be fully grammatical, rarer items dubious. For example, *-ing* adjectives such as *alarming, gratifying, mocking* form comparatives and superlatives through periphrasis not
>   morphology (Biber, Johansson, Leech, Conrad, and Finegan, 1999: 523), hence
>   *more/most alarming* instead of **alarminger/est*. Frequency data confirm this rule. The
>   only exception found in the British National Corpus is this one occurrence of
>   *boringest*: ‘…it’s always the boringest people, I’ve never seen any of them smile,
>   laugh, talk…’. There is not enough evidence to suggest that *boringest* is a competing form to the standard *most boring*. In the concordance line quoted, the speaker may
>   want to highlight how dull these people are by contrasting his/her own interesting
>   personality. The adoption of the marked form *boringest* shows individuality and an
>   unconventional streak, distancing the speaker from the people being denigrated. But
>   this is the domain of stylistics, not grammar. **There is no question that *boringest*
>   belongs to the grammar of standard English.**

([Grammaticality Judgment Tests: Trial by Error](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d630/b7e0455fbe7e1b89a298c62799d31f447505.pdf), by Wayne Rimmer)

My conclusions:

1. I have misunderstood the paragraph, and the author does indeed believe that *boringest* is grammatical.
2. The author has been guilty of a [misnegation](https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2018/11/19/misnegation-should-not-be-overestimated-i-mean-underestimated/) error and should have written *There is no question that boringest does **not** belong to the grammar of standard English*.
3. '*There is no question that...*' can mean both (*definitely is / definitely is not*), and needs the context to disambiguate it.

My question: Which of the three conclusions is the most convincing?

---

EDIT: Thank you for all the high quality answers, and to @tchrist for offering the bounty to attract them.

Comment: I can only agree with you: it's ambiguous and should have been expressed more clearly.

Comment: Probably the author meant to say "There is no question that *boringest* belongs to the grammar of ***non-standard*** English." The author mentions "non-standard" twice in the text

Comment: @Mari-Lou - isn't the author saying 'yes it is grammatical' but 'no it is not stylisticly correct'? In which case the highlighted sentence would make sense... I'm not sure that I completely understand it though.

Comment: @marcellothearcane in the text the author places an asterisk next to "*alarminger/est*" to point out its dubious/anti-conformist/nonstandard formation.

Comment: It seems a very odd sentence to write, whatever the intended meaning, since the writer had just said that rarer items are _dubious_. In other words, since _boringest_ is rare, it is dubious – meaning there absolutely ***is*** a question whether it’s part of the grammar of standard English or not. It’s hard to tell whether the writer thinks it is or isn’t, but the sentence doesn’t fit the rest of the paragraph at all.

Comment: Words that _may_ have been accepted into the lexicon that end in _ingest_ are _charmingest, swingingest, knowingest, cunningest_ and _willingest_ (I haven't got access to OED for a better assessment). If so, the 'grammatical' rule _adjectives ending in ing always form **periphrastic** superlatives_ (accepting morphology as a part of grammar) is seen to be deficient. The author here seems to be claiming that the issue of wordness or otherwise of _boringest_ is essentially [a matter of style {/semantics, idiomaticity, and the lexis?}] **not** a grammatical one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In descending order of frequency, OED citations mention *cunningest × 16,
knowingest × 8, charmingest × 4, winningest × 3, blitheringest × 2,
darlingest × 2, huntingest × 2, lastingest × 2, stunningest × 2,
swingingest × 2, triflingest × 2,* plus one apiece of *bangingest, 
bitingest, bleedingest, blingest, braggingest, carreeringest, 
cheatingest, chillingest, clippingest, cryingest, cuddlingest,
cussingest, deuouringest, fawningest, feedingest, fittingest,
flamingest, flatteringest, floorishingest, flowingest, hittingest,* (...continued...)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet (...in continuation...) *killingest, loveingest, lyingest, mouingest, oppressingest, quashingest,
ramblingest, rantingest, raspingest, ravishingest, repiningest,
rippingest, riproaringest, shiningest, signifyingest, smilingest,
sneeringest, snivlingest, snortingest, somethingest, sparklingest,
stampingest, stoppingest, surmountingest, swearingest, tattlingest,
toppingest, tormentingest, unbelievingest, understandingest, unwillingest,
whimperingest,* and *whirlingest.* Bet that’s the **somethingest** whatnot
you’ve ever seen, innit!?

Comment: It is not clear what answer you are looking for. Is it about the common usage of “there is no question that”? Or is it about the interpretation of the same expression from the extract? (which is inevitably POB to some extent).

Comment: @user067531. I was hoping for an analysis of the paragraph and its final sentence that clearly justifies the claim either that _The author thinks 'boringest' is grammatical_ or that _The author thinks 'boringest' is ungrammatical_ - because this is not clear to me. I agree that this may be considered POB, but I think it is a question that might interest others, particularly as the source of the paragraph itself deals with the issue of grammaticality. ...

Comment: ... And my post was also following the suggestion made from time to time on Meta that higher-rep users could improve the quality of this site by asking questions themselves.

Comment: I’ve no qualms with your question,  but what about contacting the author?  The only who could actually give a definitive  answer.

Comment: I think it comes down to an age old problem. Just because someone wrote it in a book doesn't mean it was written correctly. Editors miss negations all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is 1:

> I have misunderstood the paragraph, and the author does indeed believe that boringest is grammatical.

The statements to the contrary (2 and 3) rely on inferences from a reading of the rest of the paragraph where the author believes strictly in the rules he lays out. However, in examining the paragraph there is plenty of room for the overall paragraph and the final sentence, as stated, to be consistent with one another. The author does not believe that strict rules are the only basis of grammaticality; the author does not believe frequency is an assessment of grammaticality. I will offer a paragraph-level reading and then a paper-level reading to show how the author's statement is consistent with his immediate meaning and his general approach.

## Paragraph-level reading

The first four sentences introduce the use of a corpus in linguistic research. Sentence 2 states the ease of using digital corpora for studying vocabulary frequency and grammar. Sentence 3 sets up an assumption that some users of corpora make - there is a relationship between the frequency of a construction and linguistic status. Sentence 4 elaborates on that logic: common means "fully grammatical," and rarity marks it as dubious:

> A corpus is “… a body of texts put together in a principled way, often for the purposes of linguistic research.” (Johansson 1991: 3). Computer technology means that modern corpora are large and easy to manipulate, thus lending themselves well to frequency studies of vocabulary and, to a lesser extent (Granger 2002: 21), grammar. The assumption is that there is a relationship between how frequent a construction is attested and its status in the language. Common forms and structures will be fully grammatical, rarer items dubious.

Sentence 3 and 4 are both working on an assumption that frequency should be used to judge grammaticality. However, nothing identifies this as the author's own assumption; instead, the author uses language that distances himself from that assumption: "the assumption is" following two sentences sourced respectively to two other authors, Johansson and Granger.

What follows is an example of this assumption at work. The first sentence states a grammatical tendency relating to the formation of comparatives and superlatives through periphrasis (e.g. more alarming) and not morphology (e.g. (x)alarminger). The second sentence compares this rule to corpus frequency. The third sentence adds a complication to the assumption - there is one formation in the BNC that deviates from the tendency:

> For example, -ing adjectives such as alarming, gratifying, mocking form comparatives and superlatives through periphrasis not morphology (Biber, Johansson, Leech, Conrad, and Finegan, 1999: 523), hence more/most alarming instead of *alarminger/est. Frequency data confirm this rule. The only exception found in the British National Corpus is this one occurrence of boringest: ‘…it’s always the boringest people, I’ve never seen any of them smile, laugh, talk…’.

What is to be done here? The author discusses the situation of this possible counterexample. Because the word *appears* but is *infrequent*, he has to admit a lack of evidence for this to be a "competing form." In the next two sentences, the author then states a contextual reason for the usage to come up - "boringest" as an unusual form may show the distinct personality of the person using it. "Boringest" is "marked" or emphatic:

> There is not enough evidence to suggest that boringest is a competing form to the standard most boring. In the concordance line quoted, the speaker may want to highlight how dull these people are by contrasting his/her own interesting personality. The adoption of the marked form boringest shows individuality and an unconventional streak, distancing the speaker from the people being denigrated.

Now this is where I think a lot of readings make an incorrect assumption. Even if they were clear that the author was discussing assumptions made by corpus researchers, they might assume that the example affirming that *boringest* is an unusual form meant that it was an ungrammatical form. However, in the last few sentences the author has focused instead on *marked* langauge, on *individuality*, on *an unconventional streak*. That leads the author to distinguish these features - stylistics - from grammar, to say that the corpus shows evidence of stylistics.

> But this is the domain of stylistics, not grammar.

Indeed, for this author, what researchers are studying in frequency analysis is *stylistics*. The question of grammaticality need not correlate with that. Thus he makes this bold claim:

> There is no question that boringest belongs to the grammar of standard English.

Now, that is evidently a controversial statement, based on the responses to this question. So the statement may be incorrect, and it may benefit from further elaboration. However, within the context of this author's argument in this paragraph, the denotative meaning fits. Corpus frequency spoke to stylistics, not grammar, and so despite the low frequency *boringest* is (for the author) grammatical.

## Paper-level reading

Now, regarding the paper as a whole, this interpretation of the sentence fits, according to a few points of evidence:

**The abstract** sets up the paper as an examination of individual readings of decontextualized sentences as a judgment of grammaticality -

> A  standard  method  of  determining  whether  a  construction  is  well-formed  is  a  grammaticality judgment test, where subjects make an intuitive pronouncement on the accuracy   of   form   and   structure   in   individual   decontextualized   sentences ...

as compared with several sometimes-conflicting sources of evidence:

> evidence  on  the  frequency  of  usage,  from  corpora,  and  internal  linguistic  criteria

So the abstract leads one to expect that different forms of evaluating grammar will be compared, without necessarily holding one (like corpus frequency searching) as more important.

Then **the introduction** develops further an idea that, when the author is examining the assessment of error by others, he does so in a context that regards some items considered "errors" as productive language usage:

> For  instance,  **one  critic’s  error  is  often  another  critic’s  creativity**: according to Cook (2000), our natural penchant for playing with language takes us into the territory where accuracy loses its boundaries. **This process is actually associated  with  highly-developed  language  competence**  because  it  demands  great  sensitivity to language norms and awareness of occasions when they can be eased or broken.

That fits in with the author's description of the individual who used *boringest* - they are individual and creative, and may involve "highly-developed language competence." The author refers to an outside source to make this claim, but does not describe it as an outside assumption - he says "this process is **actually** associated," indicating a belief in the actuality of the statement.

By the end of the introduction, the author clarifies that he draws a distinction between obvious errors (like "four furnitures") and then suggests that there may be grammatical usage that doesn't correspond to standard rules (like his example of "boringest" suggests):

> Error is a reality of  language  use  and  **dealing  with  grammar  that  does  not  conform  to  a  rule-based  description  of  the  standard  language  presents  theoretical  and  practical  challenges**.

Note that this is an adequate response to **sumelic**'s concern that the author believes in the periphrastic rule universally, that *boringest* cannot be (a) an exception and (b) grammatical. Yet, if the author acknowledges the existence of grammar that doesn't conform to rules, then it makes sense that both examples described by the rule and its exception (*boringest*) could be grammatical.

The remainder of the paper uses responses from English language teachers to study three kinds of appeals used in arguing for grammaticality. The author takes neither of their sides. The **conclusion** assess the difficulty of using either corpus-based methods or a series of individual judgments to assess grammaticality:

> Indeed,  grammaticality judgment tests share one of the more disconcerting side-effects of the plethora of corpus studies, namely a lack of confidence in grammatical description.

In other words, corpus tests aren't very reliable at assessing grammaticality. That's the very assumption that would allow the author to state that *boringest* is grammatical despite the corpus evidence.

### Summary

Given the paragraph-level evidence and the paper-level evidence, the statement

> There is no question that *boringest* belongs to the grammar of standard English

makes sense as literally stated. It is consistent with his paragraph-level point that corpus frequency analysis focuses on stylistics and not grammar, and it fits an overall paper that compares two kinds of frequency analysis (corpus usage, individual assessments) in order to say that they have a probability of being correct but are not always so. That said, many of us readers would prefer the author elaborate on why the author thinks its grammaticality should go unquestioned.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed, closely-argued answer

Comment: This does not fit with the author's '... [C]ommon forms and structures will be fully grammatical, rarer items dubious.... There is not enough evidence to suggest that _boringest_ is a competing form to the standard _most boring_.... The adoption of the marked form _boringest_ shows individuality and an unconventional streak'. The author means  'There is no way that _boringest_ belongs to the grammar of standard English' not 'There is no doubt that _boringest_ belongs to the grammar of standard English' and has misused an expression.

Comment: It does fit with that. You have selectively quoted the excerpts; the sentence starting "Common forms..." is elaborating on the assumption of the previous sentence: "The assumption is that there is a relationship between how frequent a construction is attested and its status in the language. Common forms and structures will be fully grammatical, rarer items dubious."

Comment: In this paragraph, he is working through an assumption made in corpus-based research: that frequency proves language status. The turn from assumption to authorial assertion is highlighted by the sentence, "But this is the domain of stylistics, not grammar." He sets that up through description: "Individuality and an unconventional streak" is stylistics; a "marked form" is stylistics.

Comment: Finally, to this assertion - "There is not enough evidence to suggest that boringest is a competing form to the standard most boring" - I read that too as commentary on frequency and stylistics rather than grammar. This is not the same as "standard English," which refers to a broader field of valid usage than standardized rules alone describe. Standard English allows for "grammar that does not conform to a rule-based description of the standard language."

Comment: I wouldn't say your answer is wrong for the simple fact that the text is very confusing and open to interpretation. Your answer is coherent within itself but imo for it to work it requires a very specific understanding of some of the concepts. Standard English grammar as defined by Merrriam Websters for instance would not allow for "boringest". And "the marked form boringest" in a linguistic sense at least would mean the irregular, non-standard form of boringness.

Comment: From this it would follow that the author is saying the non-standard form is a matter of style and there is no question of it being standard grammar. But for that interpretation to work it requires that the author has made a mistake. I don't think there can be a definitive answer to this question.

Comment: I've carefully read your answer, but I fully disagree with *your* assumption and/or analysis, call it what you will. There is nothing "standard" about *boringest* it is quirky, individual, it shows an “**unconventional** streak”.

Comment: Someone who displays a "highly-developed language competence" does not imply whatever is emitted or written by them equates with *standard* grammatical usage.

Comment: I wouldn't call someone using an ungrammatical form in the only example I have of their speech "highly developed" in "language competence."  That descriptor also definitely does not imply that *boringest* is not grammatical in standard English. Quirkiness or unconventionality is not the same as grammaticality, as the author points out: "But this is the domain of stylistics, not grammar." He is saying that unconventional usages can be considered "error" while still being grammatical; the challenge is that two common methods for judging grammaticality may have difficulties distinguishing them.

Answer (score 6):

There is no question that it is confusing.

But on consideration I would vote for **answer (2)**

> (2) The author has been guilty of a misnegation error and should have
>   written There is no question that boringest does not belong to the
>   grammar of standard English.

As you noted in your question, standard dictionary definitions of 'there is no question about/that' interpret the phrase as 'definitely the case', e.g [Macmillans Dictionay](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/there-is-no-question-about-that):

> used for saying that something is definitely true
>
> *He will win. There is no question about it.*
>
> *There is no question that she has a great voice.*

According to the dictionary definition, your passage is saying it is definitely the case that 'boringest' belongs to the grammar of standard English.

But that seems to be the opposite of what the author wants to say based upon other statements in the passage :

> Common forms and structures will be fully grammatical, rarer items
>   dubious... There is not enough evidence to suggest that boringist is a
>   competing form to more boring in standard English.

Viewed from this perspective (squirm: this is the weak link, inferential evidence -- the answer really depends on how you interpret the whole passage) the author has used the phrase incorrectly.
Moving into even more speculative territory it may be a case of  confusing 'there's no question of' with 'there's no quesion that'. Here for instance is the [MacMillan definition](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/there-is-no-question-of-something) of 'there is no question of' which means pretty much the opposite of 'there's no question that':

> if there is no question of something, it definitely will not happen
>
> *They loved each other but there was no question of marriage.*
>
> *There is no question of us interfering in the running of the business.

---

Edit note: Having looked at the other answers and the comments, it occurs to me that in terms of finding an answer to the question, the word *standard* is important in the phrase: There is no question that boringest belongs to the grammar of standard English. The author is not saying that boringest is per se illegitimate -- there may be usages which don't correspond to rule-based description. He has no objections to it stylistically and surmises that it may be used to express individuality, but it is not [standard English](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Standard%20English) grammar.

Answer (score 3):

Your conclusion #1 is correct.

This sentence (as-written) is consistent with the purpose of the work. I.e. the author’s arguments support that *boringest* IS a legitimate usage.

**Context of the Sentence:**

The excerpt is taken from a section entitled "A tale of two methodologies" in which the author describes two methods by which word usage can be determined to be legitimate.

The first methodology determines legitimacy via frequency of usage, e.g. the more frequently people use the word "shoveling" makes that word more legitimate. One problem with that method is that uncommon but useful usages are viewed as less legitimate simply because they are not needed nearly as often as a more common use of the same word (this is my interpretation).

Second is an "introspective" methodology in which argues that native speakers and/or language experts should be competent to decide whether a usage is grammatical or not regardless of how frequently it has been uttered/written.

The author uses *boringest* as an example of a word with very rare usage in the British National Corpus. He speculates that it was likely accepted because it conveys an idea that is not equal to *most boring*, and that it could serve a useful purpose despite that the same forms of other words (gratifying, mocking, alarming) are absent from the BNC. The point is that the introspective method must have been used to include *boringest* (because it’s rarely used), and that it’s inclusion is significant (because analagous forms of similar words are absent).

**My Interpretation of the Sentence:**

This is where he makes the statement

> There is no question that *boringest* belongs to the grammar of standard English.

I do not believe this to be a typo since the author led up to the statement with an argument supporting *boringest* as legitimate. The converse of this statement:

> There is no question that *boringest* does **not** belong to the grammar of standard English.

...would be nonsensical in this context because the author just told the reader that it's in the BNC, and is moreover useful. Given that he spent several sentences supporting that inclusion of *boringest* in the BNC is significant, and the word is useful, he couldn’t then credibly claim that it’s unquestionably not standard English.

The author goes on to describe several studies that investigated infrequent usages. If the author had not first made the point that *boringest* **should** be included in the BNC, despite that it is not used frequently, it would not be clear that the introspective method or research on the legitimacy of infrequent usages using an introspective approach have any importance, or that the reader should care about their results.

**My Conclusion:**

The statement "There is no question that *boringest* belongs to the grammar of standard English." makes sense as it is written in the context of this work.

Comment: One thing I find problematic with your interpretation is that the introspective methodology is not actually introduced until two paragraphs later. Also, if the two methodologies disagree rather than agreeing about the categorization of "boringest" as grammatical vs. ungrammatical, then it seems like there *would be* a question, unless you think the author is saying that the corpus methodology is just wrong.

Comment: That's not problematic. The example of *boringest* illustrates why the introspective methodology is needed. The author starts off with the obvious method of determining legitimacy (frequency of use), then uses *boringest* to illustrate that it's inadequate, or at least not the only methodology, and then describes the introspective method.

Comment: To your point that the two methodologies disagree, the author would still not be able to credibly claim "There is no question...".

Comment: I don't think that the methodologies do disagree, but I think that Rimmer is saying that "boringest" is *un*grammatical according to both corpus linguistics and introspection.

Comment: I think Rimmer is saying the methodologies disagree and that he believes "boringest" is grammatical, in conflict with the first methodology. Otherwise, why would we care at all about the competing methodology?

Comment: Agreed that Rimmer could have been a LOT more clear.

Comment: I have the impression that you are equating a mention in the British National Corpus with being standard English which isn't necessarily the case, particularly if it is a low frequency occurence. Here's a quote from elsewhere in the article. (Speaking of grammaticality judgement tests) 'There is none of the arbitrariness of corpora, which collect much extraneous  and  even  non-standard  data,  or  the  subjectivity  of  solitary  introspection.'

Comment: @Jake, that’s why Rimmer used alarming, gratifying and mocking as examples. Since their superlatives are not formed by morphology, and -est forms (presumably) not found in the BNC, it is significant that *boringest* is found in the BNC. If Rimmer actually meant that *boringest* is not legitimate, the paragraph leading up to that statement would have completely undermined his conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit reluctant to post this as an answer since I don't really have anything to say on the construction "there is no question that".

However, to me the context implies that Rimmer considers *boringest* to be ungrammatical. The reason is this earlier sentence:

> For example, *-ing* adjectives such as *alarming,
>   gratifying, mocking* form comparatives and superlatives through periphrasis not
>   morphology (Biber, Johansson, Leech, Conrad, and Finegan, 1999: 523), hence
>   *more/most alarming* instead of **alarminger/est*.

Here, *alarminger* and *alarmingest* are marked with the asterisk symbol, which indicates ungrammaticality. Unless Rimmer deliberately wrote something that he thinks is false here just to illustrate the methodology that he is describing, this sentence implies that Rimmer thinks that *alarmingest* is actually ungrammatical according to some rule of standard English grammar that forbids the use of the suffix *-est* after *-ing*, and that same rule would imply that *boringest* is also ungrammatical.

A form can be used intentionally and for stylistic purposes without being grammatical in the speaker's language (or in the standard form of the speaker's language). For example, "ain't" does not belong to the grammar of standard English (although it is part of the grammar of many other kinds of English), but it is not too uncommon for standard English speakers to use *ain't* for stylistic purposes.

As other answers have mentioned, the author didn't necessarily leave out a *not.* There are other ways that this sentence could have been written to mean the opposite of what the author intended to say. The author might have mistakenly used "There is no question that" in place of another expression that would have had the correct meaning.

Comment: @JohnHennig: So the difference between "grammatical" and "ungrammatical" is a single occurrence in the BNC? That seems unconvincing. I think that if "boringest" is viewed as grammatical in standard English when used with a special stylistic function, then "alarmingest" would likewise be grammatical as a stylistic option in certain contexts. But I don't think Rimmer is saying that.

Comment: @JohnHennig:  A form can be used intentionally and for stylistic purposes without being grammatical in the speaker's language: for example, "ain't" is not grammatical in standard English, but it is not too uncommon for standard English speakers to use it for stylistic purposes.

Comment: @JohnHennig: The Wikipedia article is not being specific about what it means by "grammatical". Rimmer, and my answer, specifically talk about the "grammar of standard English". There is not just one standard of grammaticality: here is the definition of "ungrammatical" from the cited source of that Wikipedia article: "Not conforming to the rules of some grammatical system [...] grammaticality is judged in relation to what is considered a standard, but standards vary. *I never said nothing to nobody* is ungrammatical in Standard English, but conforms to the rules of its own dialect."

Comment: ([The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar](https://books.google.com/books?id=1awJAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA427#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Comment: Yes, Rimmer intends to say that '_boringest_ is "ungrammatical" [as he uses the term; I'd use "non-standard"/"not in the lexis"] while perhaps having a certain dubious quirky semi-acceptability' while he actually says it is "grammatical". The questions about who actually define/s wordness, grammaticality, and acceptability (I've run out of scare-quotes) is a red herring. Here. Elsewhere, these questions virtually keep ELU going / fighting.

Answer (score 2):

First, we must define what '[the debate about whether] *boringest* belongs to the grammar of standard English' means here. The author explains: 'Common forms and structures will be fully grammatical, rarer items dubious.' He is using 'grammatical' in the sense *considered a* [well-formed] *word on the basis of regular use as shown in the corpora studies mentioned, and, to some degree, morphology requirements*.

................

Then we need to look at the expression

'there is no question that [X is true]'.

From all that is said, the author must be summarising

'There is no question that *boringest* belongs to the grammar of standard English' as meaning

'There is no *way* that *boringest* belongs to the grammar of standard English.'

But this is not what the fixed expression actually means.

It means 'There is no *doubt* that [*boringest* belongs to the grammar of standard English]'.

'The caveat given in the [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/no+question+that) probably highlights the cause of this aberration:

> **be no question that (something will happen/is the case)**
>
> To be absolutely certain that something will happen, be done, or be
>   the case.
>
> *If you ask me, there's no question that there is something fishy going on with the company's cash flow*
>
> *I just know that if you keep working hard, there will be no question that you'll be promoted soon.*
>
> (Note: Often confused with "be no question of" doing something, which
>   means that there is no possibility that something will be done or is
>   the case.)

'There is no question that *boringest* belongs to ...' being replaced by 'There is no question of  *boringest* belonging to ...' resolves the issue.

.............

'Grammatical' should perhaps be read 'in the English lexis' to conform with the narrower definition of 'grammatical' considered de rigeur on ELU.

Comment: The writer uses 'that' rather than 'of' - are you suggesting that this is the error?

Comment: I don’t think this change resolves anything – the whole point of the paragraph is that there is very much a question. Regardless of which construction is used, anything beginning with “there is no question” is doomed to fail here. (The writer is already using _grammatical_ in the narrow sense of ‘belonging to or formed according to rules of morphology and syntax’ as far as I can tell.)

Comment: @Janus (2) How can a single word be considered grammatical or ungrammatical? Even though morphology is seen as a subdivision of grammar, I've not seen words classed as grammatical if they're 'well-formed'. // (1) I'll delete the answer soon, as I think I've guessed wrongly at what is wrong. Are you guessing that the author intends 'There is no question that whether or not _boringest_ is a word belongs to the grammar of modern English' (ie he's saying it's not a grammatical issue)? This would accord with my assertion in (2).

Comment: What I _think_ they’re intending to say is that there is no question that _boringest_ is formed by an application of rules that adheres to what is possible in English morphology (i.e., adding _-est_ to an adjective to form a superlative), and that the resulting word therefore does not break any rules of grammar in and of itself – in this case the morphological part of it only, since it’s a single word. On fifth read, I think the meaning is, “_Boringest_ is a marked, but not inherently ungrammatical formation, but it is highly marked, and there is no doubt that its usage here is not part ->

Comment: -> of the grammar that forms ‘Standard English’; it must be considered non-standard, albeit formed in a way that adheres to grammatical processes of Standard English”. Or something along those lines. But really, the entire sentence is fairly unsalveageable in the context it’s written, I think. It should have been rephrased completely.

Comment: @Janus I quite agree. **And** I've found various examples of grammatical/ungrammatical being applied to results of morphological analyses. Time to delete.

Comment: If it counts for something, this is the answer where I cast my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Without a doubt, the author intends to say that *boringest* does not belong to the grammar of standard English--at least not on the basis of the analysis of corpora.  He goes to considerable length to explain this method of determining what is and is not standard, as summarized in other answers.

Thus, he (or his editor) has made a mistake (misnegation). Or hasn't he? Is it possible that *'There is no question that...' can mean both (definitely is / definitely is not), and needs the context to disambiguate it'?*

The infamous Google NGram has many examples of the phrase *no question that*, from the proceedings of the British Parliament over centuries to a more recent U.S. presidential speech.  I found no case where the phrase needed context for disambiguation (and I did read many of them one by one).

From a journal published in India in the 19th century, and a more recent book on philosophy:

> ...  there can, I imagine, be *no question that* the sale, though it
>   might have been irregular and originally invalid, would not have been
>   fraudulent.[Calcutta Monthly Journal, 1836, p. 278](https://books.google.com/books?id=F3ZPAQAAMAAJ)
>
> There is *no question that* Rawls can begin with issues traditionally
>   understood to be part of social justice. The question is whether he
>   can keep his theory so confined.[*Institutions and Social Justice* by Ned Diver, p. 152](https://books.google.com/books?id=HjZ9zsUAWz4C&pg=PA152&dq=%22no%20question%20that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD9b7clPXjAhVWpZ4KHTK5CPU4UBDoATABegQIARA1836%20-%20%E2%80%8ESnippet%20view)

A 1993 speech about NAFTA, imports, exports, and the like includes multiple instances of *no question that*.

> Because there is no question that, no matter what you think about the
>   adequacy of the side agreements, they will raise the cost of labor and
>   environmental investments above the point where they are now. There is
>   no question that the ...[Public Papers of the Presidents of the United States: William Jefferson Clinton, 1993](https://books.google.com/books?id=eyPhAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA1674&dq=%22no%20question%20that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwio8JWemfXjAhWBqZ4KHa1vAK4Q6AEwAHoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22no%20question%20that%22&f=false)

The examples support the dictionary definition of the phrase--it needs no context for disambiguation.  The author of the paragraph quoted in the question writes books on grammar for students of English as a second language.  How did an editor miss this? Well, we all make mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first dissect the preceding passage like this:

**The author presents "the only exception":**

> The only exception found in the British National Corpus is this one occurrence of *boringest*: ‘…it’s always the boringest people, I’ve never seen any of them smile, laugh, talk…’.

**The author claims that *boringest* is not standard English:**

> There is not enough evidence to suggest that *boringest* is a competing form to the standard *most boring*.

**The author tries to explain the existence of "the only exception" by assuming that there may have been a stylistic reason that the speaker intentionally chose the ungrammatical form:**

> In the concordance line quoted, the speaker may want to highlight how dull these people are by contrasting his/her own interesting personality. The adoption of the marked form *boringest* shows individuality and an unconventional streak, distancing the speaker from the people being denigrated. But this is the domain of stylistics, not grammar.

**The problematic sentence:**

> **There is no question that *boringest* belongs to the grammar of standard English.**

I say the sentence is problematic because the preceding passage is not in line with the sentence. What the author should have said was something like "There is no **possibility** that *boringest* belongs to the grammar of standard English."

I can't think of an example where the non-count noun *question* in the construction *There is/was no question that...* can actually mean "possibility".

So I think I'd go with 2.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis, which is a useful addition to the other high-quality answers.

Answer (score -3):

**There is no question that boringest belongs to the grammar of standard English**

The meaning of this sentence is quite easy

**There is no Question**.
meaning **There is no possibility** [Merriam-Webster] Definition 2d. [1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/question)

**That boringest belongs to the grammar of standard English.**

The writer is debating word forms and uses frequency data to confirm the rule. Boringest is the exception. He then goes on to say that there is no evidence that Boringest should replace the standard form used at present. Then he makes the statement "There is no question (possibility) that boringest belongs to the grammar of standard English"

meaning **There is no possibility that boringest belongs to the grammar of standard English**

**To summarise**

> **there is no question that** ....**is an idiom** used for saying that something is definitely true

**However the Idiom is not used here**. That and the sentence taken out of context is where the confusion relating to this question has come from.